# How to get Series list elements vertically in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I need to get a transpose or columnar representation for list of Series in pandas.Below is code snippet which i have used to form lists from Series-

```
 series1.index.values.tolist()
 series1.values.tolist()
```

It gives below lists as output-
 ['A', 'B'....'Z'] , [4424180.0, 7463.0.....,34]

**Current Output-**

> ['A', 'B'....'Z'] , [4424180.0, 7463.0.....,34].

**Output required-**

```
'A'   4424180
'B'   7463
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), optionaly [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
series1 = pd.Series([4424180.0, 7463.0,34], index=['A', 'B', 'Z'])
print (series1)
A    4424180.0
B       7463.0
Z         34.0
dtype: float64

df = series1.rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')
print (df)
   a          b
0  A  4424180.0
1  B     7463.0
2  Z       34.0
```

---

```
df = series1.reset_index()
df.columns = ['a','b']
print (df)
   a          b
0  A  4424180.0
1  B     7463.0
2  Z       34.0
```

Comment: am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index' for this.

Comment: `series1` is `pandas.Series` ? `print (type(series1))`

Comment: is something difference between my series and your with real data?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Got the error, was using values function before reset_index. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135857/discussion-between-tarun-and-jezrael).

Comment: Can you suggest, how to add another column here?
max_compar.astype(int).rename_axis('Metric').reset_index(name=('L30D maxima'), ('Yesterday'))

Comment: Can you explain more? What is second column? It is count from max_compar? Is max_compar still Series?